# How do I stop style changes from applying to everything with recursive components?

Tags: html, css, angular

I am using recursive components in Angular but I am having an issue where applying a style to a class on hover is applying to all other instances of that component, but only upwards towards the parent. Here are some image examples to show what I mean with the first image being default, second with the top most component hovered, and the third with the bottom component hovered: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iDz1Y.jpg

HTML (app-bracket-team component):

```
<div class="team">
    {{isArray(team) ? 'TBD' : ('Team ' + team.teamNumber)}}
    <div class="lines-before" *ngIf="isArray(team)">
        <div class="horizontal-line-short"></div>
        <div class="vertical-line vertical-line-top"></div>
        <div class="vertical-line vertical-line-bottom"></div>
        <div class="horizontal-line-long horizontal-line-top"></div>
        <div class="horizontal-line-long horizontal-line-bottom"></div>
        <div id="upper-team" *ngIf="team[0]">
            <app-bracket-team [team]="team[0]"></app-bracket-team>
        </div>
        <div id="bottom-team" *ngIf="team[1]">
            <app-bracket-team [team]="team[1]"></app-bracket-team>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.team {
    background-color: #4b2e83;
    color: white;
    padding: 1rem;
    border-radius: 0.5rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    width: 6rem;
}

.team:hover {
    background-color: #755ea5;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could wrap the TBD in another div and apply styles for that DOM, so all its children wont get affected and only the thead will get the styles.

```css
.team-head {
    background-color: #4b2e83;
    color: white;
    padding: 1rem;
    border-radius: 0.5rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    width: 6rem;
}

.team-head:hover {
    background-color: #755ea5;
}
```

```html
<div class="team">
  <div class="team-head">

    {{isArray(team) ? 'TBD' : ('Team ' + team.teamNumber)}}
  </div class="team">

  <div class="lines-before" *ngIf="isArray(team)">
    <div class="horizontal-line-short"></div>
    <div class="vertical-line vertical-line-top"></div>
    <div class="vertical-line vertical-line-bottom"></div>
    <div class="horizontal-line-long horizontal-line-top"></div>
    <div class="horizontal-line-long horizontal-line-bottom"></div>
    <div id="upper-team" *ngIf="team[0]">
      <app-bracket-team [team]="team[0]"></app-bracket-team>
    </div>
    <div id="bottom-team" *ngIf="team[1]">
      <app-bracket-team [team]="team[1]"></app-bracket-team>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```